# After use Restore-SPSite command in another server don't see Add new Supsite

Tags: sub-site

After use Restore-SPSite command I don't see butons to Add new Supsites on Site contens, what should I do:

[image]

It's another server and another farm.

Comment: Does the user logging in to Restored site has Site Owner permissions? Can you see Site Settings options?

Comment: Yes I'm See them. But I can ' add aby site.

Comment: Are you checking the Site Contents page? Which version of SharePoint is this? Can you access the create new site page via /_layouts/newsbweb.aspx

Comment: If I take by link, it's show, but I don'tsee any template of Site and I cant choose.

Comment: I tried to make site, without any tamplate, and It told me, that the language is not good. So I install Polish language and it show button to add a site :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Install Polish language which i have got on serwer from wchich I migrated it the button to add Subsite is shown.